# Set proxy and port for Mobile Data Programatically ( android 4.x.x +)

Tags: android

Is there any way to set proxy and port for mobile Data in android 4.x.x???

I've searched every where but i could not find anything

thank you

Comment: For your app or for all apps?  On the second I would bet no-  sounds like the type of security hole Android tries to avoid.

Comment: im try to set proxy and port for whole phone